# How to define two differents close behavior for jquery ui dialogs?

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, behavior

I'm using jquery dialogs and I had to make a "ok" button which close the current dialog. I managed to do so with the option :

```
buttons: {"OK": function() { $(this).dialog("close");  }}
```

So far, so good.

The problem is, the original close button (at the top right corner) shouldn't close the dialog anymore, but ask you if you want to clean the form elements inside the dialog instead (and call a function to do so); and I can't use "beforeClose" for this because it would affect the ok button's behavior too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to capture that the close button was clicked or not (I wasn't able to find anything and I have never had to do it before). However, another alternative is to hide the close button completely and provide buttons to the user on your own. Something like this...

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        OK: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Close: function() {
            // Do stuff...
        }
    },
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {},
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        // This hides the close button.
        $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I forgot to say that the users want the clean-but-don't-close-button at the top right corner (don't ask me why lol). I have to literally invert the two button's behaviors.